# How can i get list of files from a directory?

Tags: dynamic, dynamics-nav, dynamics-business-central

I'm trying to get list of files from a directory in **D365 Business central** , because in the **`AL`** language **`DotNet`** var is not supported, so i don't know how can i get those files paths.

In my requirement i know the path of folder but need to get actual files paths in that folder.

> Ex: Folder is E:\Dynamically\
>
> But i want to get files path like:
>
> 1. E:\Dynamically\1.txt
> 2. E:\Dynamically\2.txt
> 3. E:\Dynamically\3.txt

I tried to search inbuilt function in **`Codeunit 419`**("File Management"), and tried to get using Azure function. I am adding my code for get file from that directory but it is for one file.

```
action("Import Files")
            {
                ApplicationArea = All;
                Image = Import;

                trigger OnAction();
                var
                    FromFile: Text;
                    FileMgt: Codeunit "File Management";
                begin
                    Init();
                    Message(FileMgt.GetExtension('E:\Dynamically\' + 
                    Format(GetFileName)));
                    FromFile := 'E:\Dynamically\' + Format(GetFileName);
                    "Attached File".Import(FromFile);
                    "Attched File Name" := Format(GetFileName);
                    "Attached file Extension" := 
                     FileMgt.GetExtension(Format(GetFileName));
                    Insert(true);
                    MESSAGE('Successfully Import.');
                end;
            }
```

Here's the result of my import File code.

[image]

Comment: Are you running Cloud or On-Premise?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you use **GetClientDirectoryFilesList** or **GetServerDirectoryFilesList** in *Codeunit 419* they both take *NameValueBuffer* (*Table 813*) and *DirectoryPath* (text) as arguments. You could then use *NameValueBuffer* to get all files.

These functions are probably only available for on-premise so you would have to target your extension to internal in *app.json*.